# Retirar virgula do ultimo valor do foreach em PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach

Bom dia,

tenho um foreach em meu sistem e preciso separar os itens pro virgula, então o foreach está assim

```
foreach($value as $item){ echo $item . ','}
```

o resultado, obviamente sai:

```
1,2,3,
```

como eu faço pra tirar essa ultima virgula, independente do numero de itens que eu tiver no array ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras. Pode fazer com [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rtrim.php):

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];
$text = '';
foreach($array as $item) {
    $text .= $item. ', ';
}
$text = rtrim($text, ', ');
echo $text; // 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Ou por ex, assim:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];
$arrayCount = count($array);
for($i=0; $i < $arrayCount; $i++) {
    if($i < $arrayCount-1) { // fazemos isto para todas as voltas menos para a ultima
        echo $array[$i]. ',';
        continue;
    }
    echo $array[$i]; // na ultima volta não acrescenta a virgula... 1,2,3,4
}
```

Para complementar vou deixar aqui a solução em cima mas com foreach:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];
$arrayCount = count($array);
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $item) {
    if(++$i === $arrayCount) { // fazemos isto para todas as voltas menos para a ultima
        echo $item;
        continue;
    }
    echo $item. ','; // na ultima volta não acrescenta a virgula... 1,2,3,4
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Você também pode usar `implode(",", $array);` no lugar do `foreach`.